# Method in class not being called after XMLHttpRequest is done

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, typescript, xmlhttprequest

I have the following method to log into my API:

```
login()
{
    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("admin[email]", "user");
    formData.append("admin[password]", "pass");

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "my_link");

    request.onreadystatechange = (function() {
      if (request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && request.status === 201)
      {
        return function() { this.loadMembers(); }
      }
    });

    request.send(formData);
  }
```

Then I have my method that I'm trying to call AFTER my post async request is completely done:

```
loadMembers()
{
    ....
}
```

Now for some reason, `this.loadMembers()` is never being called. If I put a testing console.log() right above it (not within the return callback) it calls just fine - so I know that the requestState and request status is correct.

Is there a better way to do this? Or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are returning a function instead of just calling loadMembers.

So instead of:

```
request.onreadystatechange = (function() {
  if (request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && request.status === 201)
  {
    return function() { this.loadMembers(); }
  }
});
```

You likely want:

```
var that = this;
request.onreadystatechange = (function() {
  if (request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && request.status === 201)
  {
    that.loadMembers();
  }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because "this" in the context of the onreadystatechange callback is XMLHttpRequest, not my class.

Comment: Okay, updated it to capture the `this` context so it is available within the function as `that`.

Answer (score 0):

Remember the "this" in login() is not the same this as the one inside the (function() { if....}) so you need to save this var that = this in the way that rasmeister shows.